# Xcode New project - dyld`dyld_fatal_error

Tags: xcode, xcode7.3

I am having problem with my current Xcode environment I think.

I have a project I am using pod for 3rd party frameworks, recently I cleaned up the ~/Library/Cache and revoked all my certificates/identifiers/provisioned profiles and created new ones.

When I run the project on device I get the `dyld`dyld_fatal_error` error, I've spent whole day yesterday trying to fix it with no luck.

Today I tried to create a new project, swift language, the default one, tried to run it in my device (iPhone 6s, iOS 9.3.1) and I got same error (screenshot):

https://www.dropbox.com/s/s610kjb91t03hfz/Screenshot%202016-04-25%2017.43.09.png?dl=0

No idea what exactly is causing the problem or how to fix it. Help is appreciated.

Environment:
Xcode 7.3, Apple Swift version 2.2 (swiftlang-703.0.18.1 clang-703.0.29), Target: x86_64-apple-macosx10.9

[edit]
Clicking on continue on debugger I get this in log

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libswiftCore.dylib
  Referenced from: /var/containers/Bundle/Application/6FB44AE2-1475-4EC0-8620-38E210C27315/test.app/test
  Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/6FB44AE2-1475-4EC0-8620-38E210C27315/test.app/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib: mmap() errno=1 validating first page of '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/6FB44AE2-1475-4EC0-8620-38E210C27315/test.app/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib'
(lldb)
```

Comment: The actual reason will be available somewhere (perhaps you have to *continue* in the debugger).  It will be something along the lines of *dynamic library not found*...  we need that information.

Comment: I edited my question with the information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in my certificates. When I opened the keychain I found certificates I generated recently had the error `the certificate has an invalid issuer`.

Then I deleted all my certificates I added from Apple Developer Center. I requested new Certificate from Certificate Authority, and used it to create new certificate in Apple Developer Center. Then downloaded it, and installed it.

I also installed WWDR Certificate from https://www.apple.com/certificateauthority/.

It worked!